# C# MySQL retrieving a value from a column matching another

Tags: c#, mysql, datareader

So I have a table with the following columns:
ID, name, adress, etc..

I have been doing some research but I cannot come across the right keywords to find out to do what I want.  I would like to be able to take the name value (Which would be say... "John Doe" which is in the database already for sure..) and retrieve the ID of it (from the int MySQL value ID).

I have come across the following code but I cannot seem to figure out how to extend its limits to match my needs.

```
  connection2.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        try
        {
            MySqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("id")));
            }
            myReader.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection2.Close();
        }
```

This is also what I have come up with to the best of my abilities.

```
        MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection("Server=" + server + ";" + "Port=" + port + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Password=" + password + ";");
        string query = @"SELECT id FROM caregiverdatabse WHERE name Like '%" + caregiverNameDisp.Text + "%'";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection2);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "take the name value and retrieve the id from it."  So, you have a variable which contains a value in a `name` column and you want to query the database to get the value from the `id` column on the same record?  For starters, is `name` unique or will there be multiple records?  Also, the code shown doesn't include the actual SQL command in the `cmd` object or any parameters, so we can't really see what needs to be changed there.  Essentially that command would be selecting the `id` where `name` matches a given value.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have edited the post with what I have tried to come up with to the best of my abilities. Hopefully it helps out!

Comment: There are a couple of potential problems with that.  First is that the query is *wide open* to what's called SQL Injection Attacks.  Read about them here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection  Essentially you never want to add user input directly into a query without "sanitizing" it first.  Consider using something called parameterized queries to help with this.  More to the point of the question, however, what is `caregiverdatabase` in the query?  Where you're using that term you should be using the name of a table, not a database.

Comment: Yes, I will have to look into that. 

Sorry about the naming. It is indeed the name of the table, I just named it that (caregiverdatabse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the hard coded parameters with sql parameters, but here is a general idea of what you'll need to do here. Using your present sql query.

```
    MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection();
    MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand();
    string sSql = "SELECT id FROM caregiverdatabse WHERE name Like '%" + caregiverNameDisp.Text + "%'";
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=" + server + ";" + "Port=" + port + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Password=" + password + ";";
    sqlCmd.CommandText = sSql;
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
    MySqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {

        results.Add((reader["id"].ToString());

    }

    reader.Close();
    sqlConn.Close();
```

Keep in mind you can add the reader results to a string, to a list like above, whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: I did this as followed and I changed it into  results = reader["id"].ToString();. The problem is that it always seems to display the last value (Which right now is ID 8).  Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, because you need results = results + reader["id"].ToString();

Comment: I get the following error along with that: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: oh I thought you changed to a string, it's still a list. You have to do the code I suggested in the answer, unless you remove
    List<string> results = new List<string>(); and change it to string results = "";

Comment: Oh yeah, did that. The thing is that it displays every index now. So basically it prints "12345" if there are 5 rows in the table. Haha so sorry for all this trouble man.

Comment: are you sure those aren't the real row ID numbers? put a breakpoint on string sSql and copy the string as it shows in the debugger, then run it in sql query window and see the results there

Answer (score 0):

this how  id en name pawe

```
        clsMySQL.sql_con.Open();
        string id = ID;
       
        sql = "SELECT *FROM test";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, clsMySQL.sql_con);
        
        
        sql_cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, clsMySQL.sql_con);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            id = dr["id"].ToString();
            user = dr["user_name"].ToString();
            pass = dr["password"].ToString();
             
            if (name.Text == user && passw.Text == pass)
            {
                string depart = id;
                Hide();

                MessageBox.Show("it works");
                // Then show the main form
                cracker form = new cracker(name.Text);
                form.sid = depart;
                form.Show();
                MessageBox.Show(ID);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login please check username and password");
        }
        clsMySQL.sql_con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Your introductory text us very difficult to understand. You should consider revising/improving it.